# Prove that the area of a triangle with inradius $r$ equals $2r(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, circles

A circle inscribed in a triangle, the radius of the circle is $r$, prove that the area of triangle is $2r(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C).$

P.s i can't seem to upload the image

Comment: Hello. Welcome to MSE. Please provide some context. What have you tried? What's the source of this question? What formulas in triangle are you familiar with?

Comment: Is $r$ meant to be the inradius, normally denoted $r$ (as my answer and your body assumes), it the circumradius (as your title says), normally denoted $R$?

Comment: @J.G it's the inradius $r$. I edited his title wrongly, but I corrected. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DougM The only trouble is the area is $4$ times less than that.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks, I was thinking  $\frac12 r(a+b+c)$  and then typed in  $2r(a+b+c)$

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly wrong by dimensional analysis. By the sine rule, your expectation is $2r(a+b+c)/(2R)=2rs/R$, with $s$ the semiperimeter and $R$ the circumradius. The area is actually $rs$. Perhaps what you really wanted to prove is that $2R(\sin A+\cdots)$ is the perimeter, which follows as above.